# Extjs with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, extjs, highcharts

I'm a new by for using Sencha ExtJs4 with HighChart. I'm trying to create chart in a panel container. But error always occurs like this.

> GET `http://mylocalhost/myFolder/highcharts/bar.js` 404 (Not Found)
>   ext-dev.js:10587
>
> Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading synchronously via XHR:
>   'highcharts/bar.js'; please verify that the file exists. XHR status
>   code: 404

please help to solve.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means that your file cannot be loaded, so please check your URLs.